# Rails console can't connect to database but rake tasks can

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a rails app that is using the one click DO image.

I can run any of the `rake db:*` successfully but when I run `rails console` I can't connect to the db.

How can I fix it? The app is working fine. So I think is a `rails console` problem.

Console output:

```
deployer:/home/rails$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (3.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

deployer:/home/rails$ echo $APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD
[redacted database password]

deployer:/home/rails$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 25038
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.6)
2.3.0 :001 > User.connection
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: rails
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
  username: rails
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**EDIT**

Looking around I found that `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` has `password: nil`. Why then the server process reads the password but console doesn't?

I added `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` to an initializer. At initialization the password is present.

On console `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` returns all the info as expected, except by the password. I even have reload the default vars with `. /etc/defaults/unicorn`

**EDIT 2**

`ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` on `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`

```
{"default"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil},
 "development"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"development"},
 "test"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"test"},
 "production"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"production"}}
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` on `APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`

```
{"default"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil},
 "development"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"development"},
 "test"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"test"},
 "production"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>nil,
   "database"=>"production"}}
```

`ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` on `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails server`

```
{"default"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>[password]},
 "development"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>[password],
   "database"=>"development"},
 "test"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>[password],
   "database"=>"test"},
 "production"=>
  {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
   "encoding"=>"unicode",
   "pool"=>5,
   "host"=>"localhost",
   "username"=>"rails",
   "password"=>[password],
   "database"=>"production"}}
```

Comment: Have you try `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console -e production` ? I have a bug once and RAILS_ENV=production do not launched the console in production mode, I have to use the -e option.

Comment: @codingaddicted the console is being started on production

Comment: Ok, can you try to force the ENV variable when you write the command, something like: `APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=yoursecurepassword RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console` ?

Comment: what happens when you are runnign the server with `rails s` and issuing a request?

Comment: @codingaddicted running `APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=password RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console` doesn't work. And I can't understand why. this is the relevant output of `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`: `"password"=>nil`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ everything works fine on the server process. Database is being queried as expected and rake tasks can read and update the database

Comment: What shows `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations` on server  start?

Comment: I guess that the important difference is the Spring preloader. Is is possible that spring was started *before* you've defined the ENV variable? Can you try killing spring and retrying console?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ check the edit

Comment: @BoraMa please add this comment as a answer. This worked for me. Ty

Comment: @NicosKaralis done, thank you :)

Comment: have you use `spring`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that the important difference is the Spring preloader. It seems that **you've started Spring *before*** you've defined the ENV variable.

Try killing Spring and restarting the console.

Comment: Command to stop spring: `bundle exec spring stop` or `bin/spring stop`

Comment: This solution saved me from an infuriatingly dense postgres error `PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user error` I kept receiving in rails console. Thanks so much!